# ActiveAdmin - make resource index show 'edit' and 'delete' but not 'view'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have a resource called `Foobar`, and on my `/admin/foobars` page I have a list of all foobars with the options `view`, `edit`, and `delete` appearing.  I only want `edit` and `delete` to appear.

**app/admin/foobars.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Foobar do
  index do
    # Here I have a bunch of columns for various fields in Foobar
    # default_actions #=> Uncommenting this line would make view, edit, and delete appear.
    actions :defaults => false do |foobar|
      link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_foobar_path(foobar)
      link_to 'Delete', admin_foobar_path(foobar), :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure"
    end
  end
end
```

My problem is that this only shows the `Delete` option - `Edit` only shows up when I remove the second line.  How do I get them to both show up under the same header?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Foobar do


  index do
    ...
    column "" do |resource|
      links = ''.html_safe
      links += link_to I18n.t('active_admin.edit'), edit_resource_path(resource), :class => "member_link edit_link"
      links += link_to I18n.t('active_admin.delete'), resource_path(resource), :method => :delete, :confirm => I18n.t('active_admin.delete_confirmation'), :class => "member_link delete_link"
      links
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

[Remove 'Show' link from ActiveAdmin default_actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075671/remove-show-link-from-activeadmin-default-actions)

Comment: does that disable the show page altogether?  I want the show page available, just not the view link in the index action set.  I know it's a strange request, but...

Comment: found it.. relly poor documentation on ActiveAdmin, but still a good plugin.

Comment: yes, the documentation is absolutely terrible.  I really hope they get their act together on that front before they release 1.0.  I guess you can't complain when you're still using 0.wtvr.

Comment: I ended up using the same `actions` block I already had, but using the link syntax you posted as its interior.

Comment: If the pop-up doesn't work for the delete action try using this line instead: `links += link_to I18n.t('active_admin.delete'), resource_path(resource), :method => :delete, data: {confirm: I18n.t('active_admin.delete_confirmation')}, :class => "member_link delete_link"` extracted from the [source code](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/index_as_table.rb#L334)

Answer (score 6):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Foobar do
  actions :all, except: [:view]
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my way:

```
index do  
  actions do |resource|
     (link_to 'link_1", url)  + "\t|\t" +
     (link_to 'link_2", url)
  end
end
```

=> it produces in views : link_1 | link 2